Removing glue from leather?
My neighbour recently managed to splatter white glue on my black leather coat and didn't tell me about it until after I had found it myself and confronted him about it. At this point it's already dried and he doesn't recall exactly what kind of glue it was. So, now I need a way to remove the glue without damaging the coat. The first thing I thought of was getting it dry cleaned but when I talked to them they told me that dry cleaning likely wouldn't remove glue. My next thoughts were isopropyl alcohol, paint remover or acetone but when I looked into them I found most claiming they would damage the leather. And soap and water isn't enough.
So, how do I remove this glue without damaging the coat?

There are sites explaining removal of white glue (polyvinyl acetate, PVA), e.g.,  https://www.hunker.com/13424014/how-to-remove-dried-elmers-glue/ Generally, long soaking in warm water will do it -- and likely remove at least the surface leather dye. Prepare to do some leather dying and polishing after it dries.

Most likely, what you need is not at all a hack. You need to contact some shop in your area specialized in dealing with leather, and ask them to support you.
Why? Because whatever will attack that glue for removal probably has the ability to destroy the leather too - either totally or partially - which you want to avoid.
And my typical joke: you always have the alternative of using fire, scissors, or covering the entire jacket in glue :)

If you are very lucky, you might be able to peel the dried glue off. I would try scratching at the edge of the spill with my fingernail. Use any harsher tool (like a knife) and you risk damaging the leather.
If that doesn't work, try dissolving it in plain water. "White glue" is often a variation of PVA glue, which is water soluble. I would soak a Q-tip / cotton bud in water and apply it only to the glue. Don't let the water touch the leather to avoid stains. If after 1 - 2 minutes the glue feels tacky again, I would wipe it away with a dry paper towel (again, to avoid stains) before soaking the next bit of glue in water.
If any of those methods work but leave a stain behind, you can soak the entire coat in clean, warm water for 10 minutes. This is best done in a tub to make sure the coat soaks evenly. Then remove as much access water as you can and let it dry. It will be heavy and may need to dry laying flat. Apply a leather conditioner once it's dry.
If none of that works, I strongly advice against trying any other chemical like isopropyl alcohol, paint remover, acetone or any glue remover. They all make leather brittle and fragile.
